# Code flow not entering the statement of nested if for changing a string to title case

Tags: java, string

This code does not work after the nested if condition. I am trying to convert a `String` to title case where as soon as a space is encountered in the string, I check the next character for lowercase and convert it to uppercase using ASCII character encoding. However it does go until the nested `if` loop, but does not execute the condition there. I have used Eclipse debug perspective to come to this conclusion

```
    public class Word {
      public static void main(String args[]) {

          String rev= "This is a string";
          char a[]=new char[rev.length()];

          for (int i = 0; i < a.length;i ++) {
              a[i]=rev.charAt(i);
             if (a[i] == ' ') {
                 if (a[i+1] >= 'a' && a[i+1] <= 'z') {
                     a[i+1] -= 32;
                 }
             }
         }  
            String title=new String (a);
            System.out.print(title);
     }
   }
```

Comment: `i < a.length - 1` as indexed by `i + 1`

Comment: Please ask *one* question per post. It's not clear what you're asking here, or why you've numbered your classes...

Comment: You have two unrelated questions in one Question.  Too broad.

Comment: why don't you use `WordUtils.capitalize(String)`?

Comment: @JonSkeet my bad for that. actually i was stuck at these 2 for past 2 hours and thought to ask in combine. had asked one query earlier as well, so wanted to save time. will take care going onwards. can you guys help  now or do i need to edit this again with separate questions?

Comment: You should definitely edit this into a single, clear question - then ask another if you really need to.

Comment: @Alex.Si want to write and solve the program myself with complete code, can use functions later but want to clear the base stuff

Comment: @JonSkeet done. thanks for advice. could you please help me out now?

Comment: It's still badly formatted, and would be much better as a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - give us sample input, expected output and actual output, in a way that we can copy/paste/compile/run. You should think about what you expect to happen if the last character in the input is `' '` by the way.

Comment: @JonSkeetmade some changes, see if it helps to answer the query. would appreciate the solution for the case you mentioned as well

Comment: You set a[I]. Not a[I+1]. Try starting with 1, and use a[I-1].

Comment: Did not get your point. Can you explain this with code? Also i did set a[i] but i also incremented in it, won't that work? If not can you please tell why? Would be a good learning for me

Comment: https://xkcd.com/208/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the given program is :

In if `(a[i+1] >= 'a' && a[i+1] <= 'z')` , a[i+1] is not initilized by a[i]=rev.charAt(i); so, at `(i +1)` index, it doesn't get any value on `a[i+1]`.

You make upper case in index (i +1) `using a[i+1] -= 32;` and on the next iteration , this index value again replace by `a[i]=rev.charAt(i)`;

Consider last character as space then use `if (rev.charAt(i) == ' ' && i +1 < a.length)` condition for handling that

Check this :

```
public class Word {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String rev = "This is a string";
        char[] a = new char[rev.length()];

        int i = 0;
        for (; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = rev.charAt(i);
            if (rev.charAt(i) == ' ' && i + 1 < a.length) {
                if (rev.charAt(i+1) >= 'a' && rev.charAt(i+1) <= 'z') {
                    a[i + 1] = (char)(rev.charAt(i + 1) - 32);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }  
        String title = new String(a);
        System.out.print(title);
    }
}
```

Output:

> This Is A String

Comment: so can you explain what was wrong in my code as well? I got the answer with your program, but would appreciate an explanation as well as to what i was doing wrong and what have you corrected. Would be really helpful for em to understand what mistake i was doing in it and how can i correct it going forward.

Comment: In `if (a[i+1] >= 'a' && a[i+1] <= 'z')` , a[i+1] is not initilized by `a[i]=rev.charAt(i);` so, at i +1 index, it doesn't get any value on a[i+1].

You make upper here in index (i +1) ` a[i+1] -= 32;` and on the next iteration , this index value again replace by `a[i]=rev.charAt(i);` @icantcode

Comment: ok. so basically my approach using this a[i] is wrong? in your code you have written a[i+1] = (char) (rev.charAt(i+1) - 32); so how does that work in your explanation? Apologies for the noob query.  Also how would i handle the case where space is as the last character of the string.

Comment: When you don't initilize a[i+1], so there has not desire value at a[i+1], so i use the `rev.charAt(i+1)` to check the value.

Comment: hmm ok, so i would follow your approach as a best practice then. let me know if there is improved version of this in the same way. also can you help the case of space as last character?

Comment: @Davidweston just answer handling of the case of space at last position as well

Comment: Use this condition `if (rev.charAt(i) == ' ' && i +1 < a.length) ` for last character as a space. @icantcode

Comment: As per your code if last character in the String is a *space*, you are checking it as i+1<a.length. So in my code input is "This is a string" which is of length 16. Now if there is a space it is of length 17. When it reaches at i=16 (for case of last character as space) it would check for 17<a.length which is not and hence exit the loop. Works fine. Suppose if there are multiple spaces how would we handle for that case?

Comment: @icantcode, you can handle it by using another loop until it doesn't get a non-space character for multiple space and after that check the `index +1` is inside the length of array

Comment: i ran the program and had one more query: why are you incrementing 'i' in the inner nested if condition. why do we need to increment the value of 'i' there and what's the purpose of that. also would appreciate the above query. thanks much. will close this once got the answers

Comment: `You make upper case in index (i +1) using a[i+1] -= 32; and on the next iteration , this index value again replace by a[i]=rev.charAt(i);` -- for solve this problem use i ++

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90626/discussion-between-icantcode-and-david-weston).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> char a[]=new char[rev.length()];
> ```

Here you create a new `char[]`.  What are the values of each character at this time?  (hint:  `System.out.println( Character.digit( a[0], 10 ) );`, or just use a debugger to inspect it)

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < a.length;i ++) {
>      a[i]=rev.charAt(i);
> ```

This is a simple and straightforward loop to copy characters one at a time from a `String` to a `char[]`.  At each iteration through the loop, the elements in the array from `a[0]` through `a[i]` are set to a meaningful value.  The elements in the array from `a[i+1]` through `a[a.length]` are not yet set.

> ```
> if (a[i+1]
> ```

Since you have not yet set `a[i+1]`, checking its value is not very meaningful.

Also, consider what happens if the last character of the string is a space ...

Comment: Can you help out with a complete solution to this with the way i have written the code?

Answer (score -1):

```
class Word {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String rev= "This is a string";
    Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("(^\\w)|(\\s\\w)");
    //taken from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer, java.lang.String)
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(rev);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
      matcher.appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group().toUpperCase());
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.print(sb.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but wanted a solution with use of built in function

Comment: Please avoid code only answer, because they are almose never helpful.

Comment: No one is going to google "title case" and want details of @icantcode's homework requirements. If Stack Exchange is about categorizing the best solutions to specific problems, are there any who would disagree that this is a better solution?

Comment: Quite interesting reason for not neither explaining your code or the reason why you've chosen it.

Comment: What I mean is, when you post code in your answer, then your answer should also contain an explanation for this code. Like how it works and why it can solve OPs problem.